# BadMethodCallException thrown with message "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::raise()"

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpmyadmin, xampp, eloquent

I am referring to the 16th(Publishing statuses) lesson of Larabook on Laracasts.
I have Laravel 4.2 installed & I get a

> BadMethodCallException thrown with message "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::raise()"

My Status.php where the method 'raise' is present is :

```
<?php

namespace SocialBucket\Statuses;

use SocialBucket\Statuses\Events\StatusWasPublished;
class Status extends \Eloquent {

/*
 * fillable fields for a new status.
 */
protected $fillable = ['body'];

/*
 * A status belongs to a user.
 */
public function user()
{
     return $this->belongsTo('SocialBucket\Users\User');
}

/**
 * Publish a new status.
 * @param $body
 * @return static
 */
public static function publish($body)
{
    $status = new static(compact('body'));

    $status->raise(new StatusWasPublished($body));

    return $status;
}

}
```

In PHPStorm it also gives me a error as

> Method 'raise' not found in class static.

But the instructor Jeffery Way uses the same method and I am unable to figure what is going wrong, as none of the other users have faced the same error in the forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Did you installed 'Laravel Commander' and updated the Provider for it?
- Did you made CommandHandler for event StatusWasPublished?
- You have to add namespace `use Laracasts\Commander\Events\EventGenerator;`
- You need to write `use EventGenerator;` before `protected $fillable = ['body'];`

[Laravel Commander Package](https://github.com/laracasts/Commander)

Comment: Thank you very much! Writing 'use EventGenerator;' did the trick.